# Laravel 5.3: firstOrCreate doesn't insert/update the values

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to update or insert a row  (if item not exists ) into the table using `findOrCreate` method

Here is my code

```
Pickupaddress::firstOrCreate(
                [
                    'art_id'=>$artId
                ],
                [

                         'address_line1' => $request->addressLine1,
                         'address_line2' => $request->addressLine2,
                         'country'       => $request->country,
                         'postal_code'   => $request->postalCode,
                         'mobile_number' => $request->mobileNumber,
                         'region'        => $request->region,
                          'art_id'        => Auth::id()
                ]
            );
```

But only the time stamp fields are updated all other columns are filled with NULL

**Edit**

Updated `strict` value to `false` in `config\database.php` but it doesn't woked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your fields as `fillable` in your `Pickupaddress` model?

Based on your post it would be something like:

```
    protected $fillable = [
            'address_line1',
            'address_line2',
            'country',      
            'postal_code',  
            'mobile_number',
            'region',       
            'art_id'
    ];
```